# Auto-attach Cloudwatch alarm to instances on Elastic Beanstalk deploy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-cloudwatch

I would like to attach a Cloudwatch alarm automatically to each instance when it's deployed from Elastic Beanstalk due to a scaling trigger up.

Is this something I can do on the AWS console or are there any command I can add to my .ebextensions folder?

Thank you